# IndexedDB synchronous api + web workers - what's the point?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, indexeddb

The [IndexedDB's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) syncronous API is intented to be used inside a [Web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/):

> The synchronous API is intended to be used only inside of Web Workers.

But since theres an ansyncronous API, whats the point of using the synchronous API in a web worker. The async API wont affect the UI thread anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous API has not been implemented in any browser so far and it is marked as a risky part of the IndexedDB standard and it might be removed. And currently only Google Chrome has implemented IndexedDB access inside web workers with async api.

References [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#sync-database), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB):

> The following features are at risk and may be removed, due to
>   potential lack of implementations.

Answer (score 8):

Synchronous API  is easier to use then async API. Async is not necessary for web worker.

Comment: Sync api is not yet available in any browser and it might be removed from IndexedDb standard. http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#sync-database

Comment: And indeed it seems that by now it has indeed been removed

Answer (score 3):

After thought, it is necessary async in web worker and even think that seemly good idea on sync API for background thread is turn out to be terrible trap.

The fact is that sync is a fake for IO wait. Whether async or sync, [internally they are same async process](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/indexeddb). Worker should be doing interesting CPU work during IO wait.

Moreover, we may already have async code for UI thread. It is better reuse async code than coding both async for foreground and sync for background.

Async API can create multiple transactions using different scope and mode. These transaction async flow are interlace. It is not possible to interlace transactions in sync API.

The only advantage we are getting on sync API is easy to use. But async workflow using promise/deferred pattern is well sort out already.

Possibly good sync API is key cursor scanning process (also for UI thread), since it does not involve serialization and likely do not need IO. However IDBCursor for sync API and  IDBCursorWithValue for async API will be confusing although use cases are different.

Seemly great idea for sync API is terrible trap for developers writing high-performance program.

Comment: When queries are made from iterating over the results of previous query then something needs to happen after nested loops are done, => mess even with promises (cases are not sorted out).   Simpler cases still more code and more error prone than similar sync examples.  In cases where you have a bunch of nested async, and therefore nested .then or callbacks, you can replace all that mess with just one callback to the ui thread when all that is done.  The code on the sender and receiver sides both are way cleaner and less bug-prone.   When lots of db code, it's worth it & can reduce code by a lot

Comment: A good indexeddb orm and models, for example, could always keep callbacks/thens to 1 for each query.   Currently you can easily have multiple nested levels to resolve simple has many relations.

Comment: I have open source library, ydn-db, that iterate multiple cursors in single callback function. Cursor iteration don't require multiple level callbacks. There is generator coroutine pattern very promising http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html#spawn still write in linear pattern, but in async.